# The right php framework for multiple profile type network

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, yii, php

i am currently in the process of planning a social network project of mine. after turning ideas & inputs in my mind for a very long time i am now starting to put thoughts on paper concretely. the network will be for a very specific group of people (so no bad facebook copy) and their industry.

the problem i am facing now is the choice of a framework or the decision to sit down and program everything ourselves. i know that there is a lot of php frameworks out there and i have spent quite a while checking the options.

i have marked zend and yii as my favorites so far from what i have seen and heard, but there is one issue i could not get information about.

the network will have 3 (in the future even 4) completely different profile types. the first type will be an institution (such as a school), the second will be someone directly affiliated by it (such as a teacher) and the third will be random people (students, parents, etc..)*.

*it will be different things of course but just so you get the idea.

-> there will be different rules of interaction between the different profile types. they will have completely different fiels to fill out, so i will create 3 different databases for them.

my question: there will only be one login, one page. which framework do you think could give me some possibilities to handle 3 different usertypes and their interaction rules? should i rely on a framework at all or should i start from scratch?

thank you for the input in advance,
sebastian =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I really Don't think you should use 3 different databases for something as futile as a User Type. Rather model user types in the single database.
2. I personally use Yii, as a Php framework, which offcourse is able to handle multiple usertypes. But I wonder if you realize what you use a framework for. I think you guys rather stop searching for the right framework, but rather lookup the right content-manager

Good luck

Comment: hi - thanks a lot for the answer, ill up it as soonas i get the req reputaion (new to stackoverflow). as for the cms i think we wont use an existing one but start from ground zwro on that. ive worked a lot with joomla and have some experience on drupal but since this will be our 'baby' we'll try to make it perfect for our needs from ground up. i meant of course 3 tables but one database. or do you think it wound e possible to manage it inone? ill look some more into yii then :)

Comment: It MUST be managed in one database. Don't start the project unless the database design is rock solid. You might want to include an ORM for mapping your php code to the database. Yii has a build in ORM, and you could do some pretty cool things just using gii, which generates the classes from databases. 
To learn the basics for any framework, perhaps start with learning MVC, if not yet familiar.

Comment: as i said one db but multiple tables i think we're on the same page. im familiar with mvc in theory as well as in iOS development. im just a little new to the web side of things :-) but thank you a lot for the answers ill start playing around with yii. ill consult with some friends here who are working in web development and will help me with the database design, even though i habe done some work with mysql databases im not 100% solid there. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I will also suggest Yii because it is strongly object oriented language and gives you ability to have heavy app behaving light weight application.

Very strong ORM is its beauty. I suggest you plan it first then take a start.first have a brief knowledge of its structure and then start

you can handle multiple profiles by [Modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module).I recently made [This](http://www.topminds.com.br/) using Yii it has 3 roles so far Admin,Teacher,Student and two of them has profiles.

Happy programming :)

Comment: hi thanks for the link - i bookmarked it, sounds interesting =) as well thank you for the hint with modules. i think my decision to use yii stands. ill have the first meeting today where we will start the detailed planning. thanks for the answer =)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before this is not a framework issue.
It might be 3 tables in one database :
- one for institutions
- one for profiles
- one for relations between those, with a status field for the relationtype.

When choosing a framework : consider it's simplicity for rapid development.